# How to make a initial view to configure the database connection in grails?

Tags: database, grails

I need a initial view in grails to configure the connection to the database, it is possible?, how do this?

"gsp like view, that lets the admin configure the database connection"

Comment: are you talking about a database view, or  gsp like view, that lets the admin  configure the database connection? You should give a little more detail in your question to get good answers.

Comment: I am talking about the second: "gsp like view, that lets the admin configure the database connection"

Comment: You want to do something like [typo3](https://typo3.org/fileadmin/t3org/images/FM-content/Installer.png) in the php world does - right? I'm not aware of any solution, that would enable you to do this with grails. As christopher already said, normally you use `DataSource.groovy` or another way is to use `JNDI` and configure the DataSource in context.xml of your tomcat. What could potentially work is to use some kind of provy-installer app, that creates the context.xml on-the-fly. But i'm not quite sure, if this works out. If you find something, i would be interested as well.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the connection to the database is done via the `DataSource.groovy` file. This is a groovy script that sets up your connection to the database.

When you create your Domain classes, you can set `scaffold` to `true` in the controller, which will generate CRUD layouts for you.

**Reading**

[The docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/conf.html#dataSource).